# memory addresses cpu 8-bit bus and 16-bit address bus

Tags: operating-system

Hi how do i find the highest and lowest memory locations expressed in hexadecimal and the the number of addressable memory locations expressed in K.

Comment: What type of operating system is this, and is this homework?

Comment: Its a practice  exam question i wasn't too sure about the operating system well it did not say. Working off the itel 8086 i think.

Comment: for an `n-bit` system (32 for 32-bit, 64 for 64-bit, etc), the lowest addressable memory location is (in binary) `00000000....` for `n` bits, and the highest addressable memory location is (in binary) `11111....` for `n` bits. You can combine 4 binary bits to be represented as a hex number, so the lowest location in hex is `0x00...` for `n/4` positions and the highest is `0xfff....` for `n/4` positions. There are 2^n different places between `0xff...` and `0x00...` and those are the total number of addressable memory locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 16 bit address bus can access 64 kb of memory.

The lowest and highest addressable memory locations are simply the lowest and highest 16 bit numbers, i.e. 0x0000 and 0xffff. However, depending on the hardware and operating system the usable RAM may be smaller. The lowest memory areas are typically used by the OS, and the highest may be overlayed with ROM or reserved for hardware interfacing.